# convert from long to symmetrical square wide format in R

Tags: r, reshape

I would like to convert this dataframe

```
tmp <- data.frame(V1=c("A","A","B"),V2=c("B","C","C"),V3=c(0.2,0.4,0.1))
tmp
  V1 V2  V3
1  A  B 0.2
2  A  C 0.4
3  B  C 0.1
```

into a square matrix like this (which should ultimately be a `dist` object

```
  A B C
A 0
B 0.2 0
C 0.4 0.1 0
```

I tried different approaches based on functions `reshape`, `spread` or `xtabs` but I cannot get the right dimension. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
d <- sort(unique(unlist(tmp[1:2])))
m <- `dimnames<-`(matrix(0,length(d),length(d)),list(d,d))
m[as.matrix(tmp[1:2])] <- tmp$V3
res <- t(m) + m
```

such that

```
> res
    A   B   C
A 0.0 0.2 0.4
B 0.2 0.0 0.1
C 0.4 0.1 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own `dist` object this way using `structure`:

```
tmp_lab <- unique(c(as.character(tmp$V1), as.character(tmp$V2)))

structure(tmp$V3,
          Size = length(tmp_lab),
          Labels = tmp_lab,
          Diag = TRUE,
          Upper = FALSE,
          method = "user",
          class = "dist")
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C
A 0.0        
B 0.2 0.0    
C 0.4 0.1 0.0
```

Comment: Smart to construct the `dist` object! +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `xtabs` after converting the columns 'V1' , 'V2' to `factor` with `levels` specified as the same

```
tmp[1:2] <- lapply(tmp[1:2], factor, levels = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
as.dist(xtabs(V3 ~ V2 + V1, tmp), diag = TRUE)
#    A   B   C
#A 0.0        
#B 0.2 0.0    
#C 0.4 0.1 0.0
```